# How to take boostrap modal inputs to insert to SQL table using AJAX through fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, fullcalendar

I have been trying for some time to get this working. I am struggling to take user input from a modal and insert it into a my database in phpmyadmin. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

1) Using the select callback I bring up a modal:

```
    select: function(start, end, allDay)
{
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
},
```

2) The modal itself in the HTML:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Event</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="FormControlInput1">Task Title</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter Task Title">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="FormControlInput2">Task Number</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number" placeholder="Enter Task Number>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="FormControlInput3">Location</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" placeholder="Enter Location">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="FormControlTextarea1">Tooling Required</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="tooling" placeholder="Enter the tools required for the task here" rows="3"></textarea>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="FormControlTextarea2">Consumables</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="consumables" placeholder="Enter the consumables required for the task here" rows="3"></textarea>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="FormControlSelect1">Safety Condition</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="safety">
                     <option>0</option>
                     <option>1</option>
                     <option>2</option>
                     <option>3</option>
                     <option>4</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="buttonAddEvent">Add Event</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

3) At this point I would like to use my insert.php file I have made, which works for other functions in the code:

```
<?php

//insert.php

$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;dbname=dbname', 'username', 'password');

if(isset($_POST["title"]))
{
 $query = "
 INSERT INTO events
 (title, number, location, tooling, consumables, safety, start_event, end_event)
 VALUES (:title, :number, :location, :tooling, :consumables, :safety, :start_event, :end_event)
 ";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute(
  array(
   ':title' => $_POST['title'],
   ':number' => $_POST['number'],
   ':location' => $_POST['location'],
   ':tooling' => $_POST['tooling'],
   ':consumables' => $_POST['consumables'],
   ':safety' => $_POST['safety'],
   ':start_event' => $_POST['start'],
   ':end_event' => $_POST['end']
  )
 );
}


?>
```

I have typically inserted data using the following code however this uses prompts() which I want to replace with the modal inputs:

```
select: function(start, end, allDay)
{
 var title = prompt("Enter Task Title");
 if(title)
 {
  var number = prompt("Enter Task Number");
  var location = prompt("Enter Train Location");
  var tooling = prompt("Enter Tooling Required");
  var consumables = prompt("Enter Consumables Required");
  var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
  var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
  $.ajax({
   url:"insert.php",
   type:"POST",
   data:{title:title, number:number, location:location, tooling:tooling, consumables:consumables, start:start, end:end},
   success:function()
   {
    calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
   }
  })
 }
},
```

Comment: "struggling" means what exactly? It's unclear where you are stuck, or what error/problem you are facing. Please clarify the specific issue.

Comment: It seems like you still need to a) add modal textboxes for the start and end dates, and populate those textboxes with selected start and end dates from fullCalendar, and then b) handle the submission of your form - I guess you want to use AJAX for that? If so you need to set a "submit" event handler on the form (for which you'll likely need to give the form an ID so you can identify it), serialise the form data and send it to insert.php via AJAX. Then refetch the events on the calendar if it succeeds. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Needed to make use of .on() to pass data from modal input to variables

```
select: function(start, end, allDay)
{
  var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
  var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
  $('#myModal').modal('show')
  $('#buttonAddEvent').on('click', function (){
    var title = $("#myModal #title").val().trim();
    var number = $("#myModal #number").val().trim();
    var location = $("#myModal #location").val().trim();
    var tooling = $("#myModal #tooling").val().trim();
    var consumables = $("#myModal #consumables").val().trim();
    var safety = $("#myModal #safety").val().trim();
    var mockEvent = {title:title, number:number, location:location, tooling:tooling, consumables:consumables, safety:safety, start:start, end:end};
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', mockEvent);
    $('#buttonAddEvent').unbind('click');
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    $.ajax({
     url:"insert.php",
     type:"POST",
     data:{title:title, number:number, location:location, tooling:tooling, consumables:consumables, safety:safety, start:start, end:end},
     success:function()
     {
        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
     }
   });
  });
},
```

Thanks to @ADyson for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it. Just a small point: you should use `.off()` instead of `.unbind()`. .off is the direct opposite of .on. unbind may have slightly different behaviour in some situations. See https://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score -1):

i 'm not seeing any return data from your php code (which is generally get newly updated record and  returns as json_encode),
and then the Ajax Success Function should process the response data and fetch it to calendar

Comment: `calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');` already takes care of that (see second ajax example). That is unlikely to be the issue.

Comment: @ADyson sorry, my bad. Newbie here, cant make a comment on question, just answering :)

Comment: It's fine to answer, however I'm just pointing out that I don't think it's the correct answer.